# Show that $V := \left\{ y \mid y'' - y^2 = 0 \right\}$ is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I am not sure which one of the conditions is not satisfied. I don't see why solutions to $y'' = y^2$ would not commute or be associative or satisfy all the distribution properties. The zero vector is there as $y=0$ is a solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try linearity..

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $y$ is a non-zero solution. Consider $(2y)''-(2y)^{2}=2(y''-2 y^{2})=-2y^{2}\neq0$.